# What is the best way to constrain the type of an array to be a local array with contiguous data in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

Consider the following Chapel function:

```
proc myfunc(arr : []?T) {}
```

I'd like to guarantee the array (at compile time) to be

1. local
2. the underlying data is stored in a contiguous memory block.

What is the best way to do this?

A possible application of this would be a case where one is calling out to a C function inside of `myfunc`. Doing this at compile time as a constraint might allow one to overload `myfunc` to take a fast path if 1 & 2 are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official user-facing way to make such queries as of Chapel 1.22, though it would be reasonable to file feature requests on [Chapel's GitHub issues page](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) requesting such capabilities.  In doing so, note that there is a subtle difference between knowing whether an array is stored in a single contiguous chunk vs. stored on a single locale vs. stored locally (e.g., an array could be stored in a single contiguous chunk yet on a locale that was distinct/remote from where the query is being made).  The Chapel compiler could generally answer the first two queries statically, but the third could only be answered dynamically since it's not generally possible to reason at compile-time about the locales on which variables are stored.

An internal / developer-oriented query that could potentially be used as a stopgap in the meantime is the `.isDefaultRectangular()` query which is implemented for domains and arrays and relied upon for making such queries in the implementation.  It indicates whether or not the domain or array is implemented using the default domain map for rectangular domains and arrays.  This domain map is, by nature, non-distributed and stored contiguously.  The following example shows its behavior ([TIO](https://tio.run/##dVC9CsIwEN7zFEenBkqhulkcin0CJ6E4hPTUQKwlSRURn73e1SgquNzB95uLPqge7TgOHmF11dbo2vhQCnFWDmp70rCEW5Hn8wx43suJqIhYQMP8Fhwq@zK0ZP5xQHtUfY9tjE/TIiukjDms5yDe76TeUW1AH0xIO3XEDDYSbgLg4kxA20UwyY2vcacGG9aog@r2g1UuldSfkOUPS813IWJ6wheQmBcRL7R6otU3Oj2Sxbw/1RGvfnBP12KMaWbTh/DcynIcHw)):

```
use CyclicDist;

// declare a local / non-distributed domain and array
var Dloc = {1..3, 1..3};
var Aloc: [Dloc] real;

// declare a cyclically-distributed domain and array
var Ddist = {1..3, 1..3} dmapped Cyclic((1,1));
var Adist: [Ddist] real;

// generic function that queries whether or not its argument uses the
// default rectangular domain map
proc testit(name, X) {
  writeln(name, ".isDefaultRectangular() = ", X.isDefaultRectangular());
}

// various calls to the generic function
testit("Dloc", Dloc);
testit("Aloc", Aloc);
testit("Ddist", Ddist);
testit("Adist", Adist);
testit("slice", Aloc[2..3, 2..3]);
```

where the output is:

```
Dloc.isDefaultRectangular() = true
Aloc.isDefaultRectangular() = true
Ddist.isDefaultRectangular() = false
Adist.isDefaultRectangular() = false
slice.isDefaultRectangular() = false
```

This query returns a `param` result, indicating that its results are known at compile-time.  Thus, when it returns `true`, it's indicating that the array is stored in a single chunk on a single locale, but isn't saying whether or not it's the locale on which the query is being run.  To do that, an execution time `X.locale == here` check would need to be used.

Also, note that it returns false for the case of a slice of a local array.  This may or may not be what you want because though the underlying array is still contiguous and local, the elements described by the slice may not necessarily be.

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer! Quick followup -- Is `DefaultRectangular` "guaranteed" to be contiguous at a spec level, or is this just at an implementation level? And does the Chapel 2 stability guarantee apply to this?

Comment: I would say that nothing about the `isDefaultRectangular()` query itself is guaranteed, hence the feature request suggestion.  But I think you're asking whether default rectangular arrays can always be assumed to be contiguous.  I don't believe the language specification currently requires them to be, and I might imagine that some exotic architectures might not want to make them so.  However, I don't anticipate them to become otherwise in the common case / near-term as some of our past attempts to implement them using multiple chunks blew up on us performance-wise.

Comment: Something else I  meant to touch on in the original reply, but forgot to:  For a multi-dimensional array, I could also imagine needing/wanting queries about whether the dimensions were laid out in row-major or column-major order (or some other ordering).  Similar to the above answer, DefaultRectangular currently defaults to row-major order, but I don't believe the language specification guarantees that.  I could imagine deciding to have it fix both of these things by default if that would be of value.

Comment: For the record, this is now captured as https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/15790